# Read one or two variables alternately in one line

Tags: kotlin

I have declared 2 variables to read from console but on other case i want to read just one of them but i can't.

My code:

```
print("Enter two numbers in format: {source base} {target base} (To quit type /exit) ")
val (sourceBase, targetBase) = readLine()!!.split(" ")
```

`I can't type /exit because i've got IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Any tips?

Edit: Thank you all for respond, especially lukas.j, it's working now.

Comment: Maybe read the line into a variable / split it into a list, and check its contents before you assume it's two things separated by a space? That destructuring call (`(sourceBase, targetBase) = list`) only works when the list has at least two elements, and you already know that won't always be true

Comment: If the line you read _might_ not contain two words, then you won't be able to split it that way. So don't! Read the line, check what it contains, and split it only if it _does_ contain the two words you're interested in, taking other action if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second element, an empty string, if the splitted readLine() contains less than 2 elements:

```
val (sourceBase, targetBase) = readLine()!!.split(" ").let { if (it.size < 2) it + "" else it }
```